# Firebase Query Not Returning Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, calendar

I'm making a calendar that stores its events in a firebase JSON, but I can't get it to find the events.

My JSON is based off the one on the JSON tutorials about dinosaurs seen here.
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

mine is arranged as follows

```
"Calendar":{
    "Zumba":{
       "Time": "1:00PM",
       "Date": "02/02/2016"
    }
    "Spring Cleaning":{
        "Time": "2:00PM",
        "Date": "02/05/2016"
    }
}
```

The way my page works is that when a day on the calendar is clicked it returns the date. Then I ask firebase to find events based on that date. Here is the code I'm using.

```
var ref = new Firebase("(firebaselink)/Calendar");
ref.orderByChild("Date").equalTo(date).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = snapshot.key();           
});
```

It should be that when I click on 02/02/2016 output will say "Zumba", but currently it just says "Calendar" if I click any day.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `on("child_added", function(snapshot)` as "value" returns the entire content.